# Header container in navigation is not visible

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm having an issue with the header.main-header element. Header is not visible in viewport. I inserted a height value to make it visible. Can someone help me and explain the reason why it's not visible when there is no height inserted.

```css
.main-header {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0 3em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 85px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-left {
  float: left;
}

.nav-right {
  float: right;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,0);
}

.nav-right li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
 <nav class="main-nav">
  <ul class="nav-left">
   <li><a href="">Try Dropbox Business</a></li>
  </ul>

 <div class="middle">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/Dropbox_logo_%28September_2013%29.svg/200px-Dropbox_logo_%28September_2013%29.svg.png" alt="Dropbox Logo" />
 </div>

  <ul class="nav-right">
   <a href="#">Download the app</a>
   <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Here's my work in Codepen:
http://codepen.io/marcvs/pen/Gjwdov?editors=1100

Also, regarding the positioning of the elements inside the nav, I tried my best to position the elements from left/center/middle. But the right side of the navbar is extending to the right and it gives a bottom scroll bar. What is the best technique to postion the elements?

Kindly give me tips to improve my work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add so much style to accomplish that header:

Start by looking at your main-header tag. If the main header's width is 100% of the page, the child block nav will also be 100%.

Now, using percentages, make your menu fit the header. there are 3 children within the nav so you could set each width to 1/3 of the width and that should make them fit. Just keep in mind that borders and padding count (Try 30% width for each, having them with float:left on all 3 of the children).

Comment: Thank you. It also works. Can you please check my codepen again. I used the technique you've provided but I don't understand why there is a space in the right side of the navbar and it extends far to the right.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I am not sure of the space you are mentioning.

Comment: Sorrly for the late reply. My problem is already resolved. I appreciate your time. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to put clear after last ul where is float:right;

Because you have float, and parent element doesn't have height when float is there.

So after last ul put div class="clear" with css .clear {clear:both;}

Or if you are using bootstrap you have class clearfix. pun in nav class="main-nav clearfix"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works. I updated it in codepen. There is another problem where the right side of the nav is extending to the right.